# Display an image on collision of two objects

Tags: coronasdk

I am working with CI and want to display an image when two objects collide with each other, at that time a specific image is displayed and that image should displayed be only for the very short duration in which the collusion occurred.

It seems like a poof function or something like this. But I cannot understand how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i will give some sample code for your question.one animated boy collision with other object(coll1).

```
animatedboy.collision=function(self,event)
if event.other.name == "coll1" then
    picture.isVisible=true

function updateTime()
       display.remove(picture) or picture.isVisible=false
end
timeTaken = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, updateTime, timerTicks )          

end


animatedboy:addEventListener( "collision", animatedboy )
```